# Приведение типа в списках инициализации, как лучше?

Tags: c++, конструктор

У меня в классе есть поле `std::uint64_t m_value`. В конструкторе по умолчанию я пишу в списке инициализации `: m_value(0)`. Работаю с разными компиляторами, при этом можно в настройках проекта отрегулировать вывод предупреждений. Некоторые никак не реагируют на такую инициализацию, некоторые пишут что-то про приведение типа.

Вопрос: надо ли продолжать писать так или же стоит явно прописывать приведение типа, например, `: m_value((std::uint64_t)(0))`, или через `static_cast`? Как считается лучше всего делать? Я понимаю, что неявное приведение типа, конечно же выполняется, но может имеет смысл для читающего код человека показывать, что имелось ввиду?

Comment: Какой компилятор ругался и каким сообщением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет никакого смысла использовать приведение типа. 0 - это константное выражение, можно сказать, "универсальный" литерал для скалярных и тем более арифметических типов. К тому же все статические объекты инициализируются нулем компилятором, то использование 0 в данном контексте в списке инициализации конструктора выглядит вполне естественно и не вызывает вопросов. Напротив, использование приведения типов может породить вопросы зачем это делается.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, дело вкуса...
Если бы это был шаблон - я бы выполнял приведение к типу-параметру `T`, но в вашем случае ведь проще использовать литерал соответствующего типа - ну, там, `0llu`...